# Need a low cost VPN solution for two offices, looking for suggestions

Tags: vpn

Need a low cost VPN solution for two offices, 14 employees.  Neither office location currently has a VPN router in place.  Also several remote users who RDP into workstations.

Comment: Sorry, shopping questions and product recommendations are considered off-topic. Please read the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq).

Answer (score 1):

I personally use [Open VPN](http://openvpn.net/) as a Virtual Appliance. Works well...

Comment: Will this work with a non-VPN routers place?  My intent is to connect two offices on the same domain.

Comment: Absolutely, you can do a site-to-site VPN with Open VPN. here is a good article: http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/security/security-howto/30353-how-to-set-up-a-site-to-site-vpn-with-openvpn